# How do I replace record if one variable has changed?

Tags: php, mysql

I am taking a calendar feed with a PHP file and I need to compare it to my database.  If the `$lastEdited` variable is different than what is in the database, I need to change the record.  I'm really new to SQL, so I'm not sure what to do.  I just have `Date_Edited` set as a VARCHAR so I just need to compare the strings.  I have this:

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM  myTable  WHERE Event_ID='$id'";
  $result = mysql_query($query);

  if (!mysql_num_rows($result)) {
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO myTable (Event_ID, Date_added, Date_edited, Title)
     VALUES ('$id', '$dateAdded', '$lastEdited', '$title')");
  }
```

How do I compare `$lastEdited` to `Date_edited` and change the row if they are different?

Comment: Do you want to compare $lastEdited to Date_Edited or Date_added

Comment: Date_Edited....oops edited the error

Comment: But I'd suggest you to use a TIMESTAMP to store date instead of VARCHAR.

Comment: Fine with me. :) I switched it to TIMESTAMP.  Still not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I seem to be getting an error where a variable is carrying over into the next rows and changing other rows titles.

Comment: Could you post the query you used and the error you got.

Comment: got it... :)  I was being confused by the added date-vs the actual date of the calendar event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do something like

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

if($lastEdited != $row['Date_added']){
   # run update query
     mysql_query("update myTable set 
         // here insert all update fields you need like
        Date_added = '$dateAdded', Date_edited = '$lastEdited' ,  Title = '$title'
        WHERE Event_ID='$id' ");

}
```

Comment: hmm.  I can't seem to get this to work.  (btw I made an error above-I want to compare $lastEdited with Date_edited) but I still am not getting this to work for me.  You want this right below the other conditional that I have up there?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html) statement.